# Regex to capture everything up to (but not including the 1st space and hyphen)

Tags: regex

Here is my samples string

```
Google Chrome-Helper -type=renderer -field-trial-handle=1
```

But I want just `Google Chrome-Helper`

Ive tried: `^.*[ ][-]` but captures up to the last parameter.

[Example Here](https://regex101.com/r/4BdeEf/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use lazy dot matching and either use capturing or a lookahead:

```
^(.*?)\s+-
```

(your value will be in Group 1) or

```
^.*?(?=\s+-)
```

See the [regex demo with capturing](https://regex101.com/r/4BdeEf/2) and [with a lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/tetf5g/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `.*?`  - any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible (i.e. the subsequent subpatterns are tried first, this one is skipped, the regex engine only comes back here if they fail to find a match)
- `(?=\s+-)` -  a positive lookahead that requires 1+ whitespace and then a hyphen.